# c# WindowsPhone Organise Code in Pivot App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivotviewer

I'm writing my first Windows Phone app using the Pivot functionality.  From what I understand it's pretty much a single view/page, that can be manipulated to show different data.

Each pivot item would be a distinct view in my mind.  So how would you organise the code in an MVVM type way?  Is this possible?  By this I mean having a different view model for each pivot item, and binding data in the pivot items to the different viewmodels?  As you only really have a single view, how can you set the datacontext to the different viewmodels?  Should this be done dynamically when a new pivot item is displayed?

Is there a different preferred architecture model for pivot applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have a pivot view deriving from `PhoneApplicationPage` containing a `Pivot` control and a corresponding parent view model. For each pivot page you create a child view model and aggregate this in parent view model and you also create corresponding views derived from `UserControl` for the view models. You then aggregate the child views inside the pivot binding them to the child view models either manually or through databinding.